# CakePHP caching

Tags: php, caching, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to enable caching for my site (still on a local machine) to have faster calls when going live (in a certain page, I have 111 SELECT sql queries) and I'm stuck a bit.

I went to app/config/core.php and enabled the `Configure::write('Cache.check', true);` line and went to my controller and added the following lines:

`var $helpers = array('Cache');

var $cacheAction = "1 hour";`

When I access my controller, I don't have any folders created under the app/tmp/cache and in the View I have added the sql_dump element which is still outputting the 111 queries all the time.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have technically completed all the steps to enable view caching, so I would suspect it has something to do with being unable to write to the cache folder.

Make sure you have your error reporting set to at minimum error_reporting(E_ALL); to see if PHP complains about a permission issue.

Furthermore, check to see if you have chmod'd the tmp dir (and subdir's) correctly. I can't remember off the top of my head the correct permission (I think 775), but 777 will definitely work (but not as secure).

Comment: Thanks John.  That was actually the trick. I didn't have the views folder in the app/tmp/cache created and no errors where popping up (while for the models/persisent folders, I was getting errors, so I didn't taught I needed to create them manually).

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1382/Clearing-the-Cache - I cached an element by passing the "cache" key in the array and the cache file was created which in it I have a list of categories.  When i update a category, nothing happens.  Any idea why? (i know its off topic but i find it spammy opening a new one)

Comment: the url i'm caching is creating a file category_id_name.php which category forms part of a route but through logs, when saving the Category model, it's trying to delete categories files. infact when i changed the route to categories, it worked fine.  Guess i have to a find a solution for this.